# Redshift UPDATE uses Seq Scan very slow

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have to update about 300 rows in a large table (600m rows) and I'm trying to make it faster.

The query I am using is a bit tricky:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET name = CASE WHEN (event_name in ('event_1', 'event_2', 'event_3')) 
THEN 'deleted' ELSE name END
WHERE uid IN ('id_1', 'id_2')
```

I try to use EXPLAIN on this query and I get:

```
XN Seq Scan on my_table  (cost=0.00..103935.76 rows=4326 width=9838)
   Filter: (((uid)::text = 'id_1'::text) OR ((uid)::text = 'id_2'::text))
```

I have an interleaved sortkey, and uid is one of the columns included in this sortkey.
The reason for why the query looks like this is that in the real context the number of columns in SET (along with name) might vary, but it probably won't be more than 10.
Basic idea is that I don't want cross join (update rules are specific to the columns, I don't want to mix them together).
For example in future there will be a query like:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET name = CASE WHEN (event_name in ("event_1", "event_2", "event_3")) THEN 'deleted' ELSE name END,
address = CASE WHEN (event_name in ("event_1", "event_4")) THEN 'deleted' ELSE address END
WHERE uid IN ("id_1", "id_2")
```

Anyway, back to the first query, it runs for a very long time (about 45 minutes) and takes 100% CPU.

I tried to check even simpler query:

```
explain UPDATE my_table SET name = 'deleted' WHERE uid IN ('id_1', 'id_2')
XN Seq Scan on my_table  (cost=0.00..103816.80 rows=4326 width=9821)
   Filter: (((uid)::text = 'id_1'::text) OR ((uid)::text = 'id_2'::text))
```

I don't know what else I can add to the question to make it more clear, would be happy to hear any advice.

Comment: You actual query must be fairly different since the WHERE keyword in your CASE statement would cause an error. Is there a sub-select in there? Also, what is the distkey on the table?

Comment: Ah, indeed, corrected it now.

Comment: Your query looks okay to me. I haven't had much luck with interleaved sort keys myself. Filtering on a column not part of the sort key I still got around 10x improvement using compound sort key vs. interleaved. Filtering on a sortkey column should be even better. We gave up using interleaved keys until Redshift gets them sorted out.

Comment: Other suggestion I have is that you try and find other ways to limit the search. If there's a timestamp for example. If you know the events you're looking for had to occur in the last couple days, you could greatly limit how much of the table to look at. Any field that's one of the sort keys should help.

Comment: Unfortunately the idea is to basically edit all the events for given uid. So there is not too many ways to constrain it further. But thank you for suggestion!

Comment: "Basic idea is that I don't want cross join (update rules are specific to the columns, I don't want to mix them together)" can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Let's say I want to filter on condition_1 and condition_2 if event_name in (event_1, event_2), and on condition_1 if event_name in (event_3). So just doing "WHERE condition in (condition_1, condition_2) and event in (event_1, event_2, event_3)" won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing the interleaved sort key and replacing it with a simple sort key on `uid` or a compound sort key with `uid` as the first column?

Also, the name `uid` makes me think that you may being using a GUID/UUID as the value. I would suggest that this is an **anti-pattern** for an `id` value in Redshift and especially for a sort key.

Problems with GUID/UUID `id`:

- Do not occur in a predictable sequence

  - Often triggers a full sequential scan
  - New rows always disrupt the sort
- Compress very poorly

  - Requires more disk space for storage
  - Requires more data to be read when queried

Comment: Yeah, uid is MongoId string. Just realised that the sortkey at least most likely didn't work, since out of 600mil rows only a few millions were sorted. This maybe warrants another question, but maybe you could suggest something: if a table is so large that vacuuming takes too long, and deep copy requires more disk space than available, what could be another way to reindex the table?

Comment: It depends on how large the table is TBH. With a truly huge table you could look at splitting it into smaller tables that contain a limited data set (e.g. a week or month) and a `UNION ALL` view over them to replace the original table. You didn't mention your `DISTSTYLE` - I would try using the `uid` as the distribution key with the sort key on a timestamp column.

Comment: If you don't have space you could do an incremental UNLOAD to S3, DELETE the range you unloaded and then COPY from S3 back to a new table. Also, if you have space issues and haven't enabled compression yet this would be a great opportunity: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Compressing_data_on_disk.html.

Comment: @JoeHarris I am using a GUID distkey with a timestamp sortkey and queries filtering on the distkey are quite slow. Queries not using that filter are super fast.

Comment: Very expensive to find a single GUID value and making it the dist key doesn't really help in that respect. Try adding it to your sort key. It will make vacuuming more expensive (because of issues mentioned above) but should improve query perf.

Answer (score 0):

update in redshift is delete and then insert. Redshift by design just mark the rows as deleted and not deleting them physically(ghost rows). Explicit **vacuum delete only < table_name >** required to reclaim space.

Seq. Scan impacted by these ghost rows. Would suggest to run above command and check the performance of query later.